# QtCreator can't find lastfm library file liblastfm.so.1 on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qmake, last.fm

I'm doing a project in C++ for school in which I decided to use LastFM's library ([github repo](https://github.com/lastfm/liblastfm)). I followed the instructions and installed it and all the dependencies but when I put `LIBS += -llastfm` in the *.pro* file in Qt as stated in the *'Using liblastfm'* section from the repo, I get the error "File liblastfm.so.1 could not be found".

I went to the library's folder in '/usr/include' (as far as I remember) and found three files:

1. liblastfm.so
2. liblastfm.so.1
3. liblastfm.so.1.0.8

These files were organized as following: *liblastfm.so* was a link to *liblastfm.so.1* and *liblastfm.so.1* was a link to *liblastfm.so.1.0.8* which was, in fact, the library file. I'm assuming they did this for easy maintenance when it comes to updates but as far as I could tell QtCreator doesn't know how the follow the link since it's finding the *liblastfm.so* but can't reach *liblastfm.so.1*.

I tried to delete the *.so* and *.so.1* files and then rename the *.so.1.0.8* file into just *liblastfm.so* but it still said that it can't find the *.so.1* file, which was kinda' confusing.

I also tried addid the library manually by right clicking the project and select "Add library" but when I reached the liblastfm's folder, only the *liblastfm.so* file was recognized as a library file and if I added it, the same error occured.

So, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where have you installed the libraries to? Could you please check the exact location?

Comment: The exact location is /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Comment: Still. I used MusicBrainz library.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment about the installed location, it seems you would need to add this in your qmake project file:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -llastfm
```

The reason is that, you seem to have installed lastfm into a "custom" location which is not in the library path by default. Hence, you need to tell qmake where to look for the lastfm libraries.

Comment: I added and still the same error: `/home/bogdan/build-lastfm_api_test_v4-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_GCC_32bit-Debug/lastfm_api_test_v4: error while loading shared libraries: liblastfm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Press <RETURN> to close this window...`

Comment: @BogdanRaducan: what is lastfm_a‌​pi_test_v4? Can you provide a self-contained example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: *lastfm_api_test_v4* is the name of my project. That's the standard error printing in the console: *project_name: error*. It's simply a new Qt Console Application project in which I ONLY try to include the library. I don't understand what you mean by 'self-contained example'.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The self-contained example is very simple. On a machine with *Linux Mint 16* I make a new **Qt Console Application** named *lastfm_api_test_v4* and in the **.pro** file I have [.pro file content](http://pastebin.com/fzGVkvL4).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue... In any case, install lastfm from your package manager, not with a custom build...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44915/discussion-between-bogdan-raducan-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: I don't really understand how to install the lastfm library from my package manager. I simply downloaded the archive from the github repo and installed it with cmake. Is there another way?

Comment: @BogdanRaducan: which distribution are you using?

Comment: Also, why would you include the dependencies of your dependencies in _your_ application?

Comment: Because that's what it said in the GitHub repo. _Your link line needs to include the following:

-llastfm -lQtCore -lQtNetwork -lQtXml_. 

I need to do this because the library uses, for example, QtNetwork and it can't do it unless I include the library in my project.

I am using Linux Mint 16 on 32 bits.

Comment: @BogdanRaducan: have you resolved that nitty-gritty details I cannot ee?

Comment: no, I eventually let it down; besides the library including problem, I discovered that the library was specially made for Qt 4 and was including some Qt libraries that were not working anymore in Qt 5. Thanks anyway for the help until now.